# Aurora Serverless Connection - Using jdbc

Tags: amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

Is it possible to connect Aurora ( MySQL ) using the jdbc driver endpoint using workbench or any other tool from my local machine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course, yes. It is same as a usual Aurora database but is serverless. You can connect it by using workbench or any JDBC driver. However, the serverless Aurora cannot be assigned by a public ip, which means that the DB is not accessible from the outside of VPC. Since it is private, you cannot access it directly.

In order to access a private DB, you need a proxy instance, EC2 instance inside of the same VPC with public ip or you can use AWS Direct Connect.

There is some explanation about AWS Direct Connect that can be used to resolve your case.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/aurora-serverless.html

This will explain how to connect the private RDS from local by pass the public EC2.
https://medium.com/@carlos.ribeiro/connecting-on-rds-server-that-is-not-publicly-accessible-1aee9e43b870
.

Comment: I did the same thing with NAT and a router table. However, the connection ended up with a timeout error. Have you ever tried this? Because I also read some articles about aurora serverless. Since it's serverless, it doesn't have any instance that runs all the time. Please let me know if you I am missing something

Answer (score 0):

For those who don't want to use EC2 as a proxy and need a solution without using Direct Connect:

Have a look at Amazon Client VPN. Using this tool (in the VPC service), you can configure a connection to the VPC where the database is located and connect to it through VPN.

Here is a guide how to configure Client VPN: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpn/latest/clientvpn-admin/cvpn-getting-started.html#cvpn-getting-started-certs